# JAVASCRIPT concatenar

Tags: javascript

Está dando erro nesta linha, como faço para concatena-la?
O motivo de eu estar fazendo isso é que quero que ao usuário clicar invoque a função de deletar o cd e passe o ID!

```
 html += '<a onclick=excluirCD('+rows[i].id_cd+')>'excluir'</a>';
```

Comment: Esse `rows[i].id_cd` é um numero ou string? e `excluir` é texto ou uma variável?

Comment: peço desculpas @Um Programador

Comment: É um numero @Sergio, consegui resolver desta forma:

Comment: Ou seja, poderia ter resolvido assim também? `html += '<a onclick=excluirCD('+rows[i].id_cd+')>excluir</a>';` Estou achando que isto é erro de digitação, tinhas aspas onde não devia.

Comment: Consegui resolver, como faço para pegar na minha função de excluir este ID que esta sendo passado chamando a função onclick=excluirCD

Answer (score 1):

Se excluir é texto, então não precisa de aspas e podes fazer assim:

```
html += '<a onclick=excluirCD(' + rows[i].id_cd + ')>excluir</a>';
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, como faço para pegar na minha função de excluir este ID que esta sendo passado chamando a função onclick=excluirCD?

Comment: @MarcosRicardo isso é uma tabela de HTML só com os dados de `rows` certo? e esse ID é unico certo?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Função que realiza select no banco para mostrar todos os cd´s registrados
//consegui resolver desta forma
function selecionarDadosDoBanco() {       
    conexaoDB();        

    $query = 'select * from tbl_cd';
    conexao.query($query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err){
            console.log("erro ao selecionar dados do banco para amostragem");
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }    

        var html = '';
        var id = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>';
            html += rows[i].nomecd;
            html += '</td>';
            html += '<td>';
            html += rows[i].preco;
            html += '</td>';  
            html += '<td>';
            html += rows[i].data;
            html += '</td>'; 
            html += '<td>';
            html += '<a href="onclick=excluirCD('+rows[i].id_cd+')">';
            html += 'excluir';
            html += '</a>'; 
            html += '</td>'; 
            html += '</tr>';                
        }

        $("#tblCd tr").after(html);
    });
    conexao.end(function(){});
}
selecionarDadosDoBanco();

//como faço para pegar este id na outra funcção agora???
function excluirCD() {      
    var id = ?

    //Verifica se um cd foi acionado
    if(id == null)
    {
        alert('erro ao tentar excluir!');
    }
    else
    {
        conexaoDB();

        con.query('DELETE FROM tbl_contatos WHERE ?', [{"id_cd" : id}],  function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(err){
                console.log("erro DELETE.");
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
        });

        connection.end(function(){});
    }
}
```